# error while trying to connect with a cisco 2600 router through python in windows

Tags: python

```
The code i have given is 
import telnetlib
HOST="X"
user ="X"   
password="X"
en_password="x"

tn=telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)




 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
        tn=telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 209, in __init__
        self.open(host, port, timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 225, in open
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
        raise error, msg
    error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

This is the error that i am getting while i am trying to connect to the 2600 router . How to remove this error , and connect to the router through a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a connection timeout - if you're not having a other networking issues then it's simply that the router is not accepting connections on the default telnet port.  Are you sure you can connect via port 23?  Can you use a telnet client to connect?